# JuMP: Issues of expecting float64, typeError: in typeassert, expected Float64, got ForwardDiff.Dual with autodiff = true and problems with exp()

Tags: julia, julia-jump, autodiff

So I tried to make a minimum example to ask questions based on a more complicated piece of code I have written:

1. A HUGE common error I'm getting is expecting float64 and instead got ForwardDiff.Dual - can someone give me a tip how in general I always make sure I avoid this bug. I feel like every time I do a new optimization problem I have to reinvent the wheel to try to make this go away
2. Apparently you cannot autodiff the julia exp() function? Does anyone know how to make it work?
3. A workaround is I did a finite sum to approximate it via the taylor series. In my one function if I had 20 terms the autodiff worked, but it wasn't accurate enough - so I went to 40 terms but then julia told me to do factorial(big(k)) and then when I try to do that with autodiff it doesn't work now - anyone have a fix for this?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
using Cubature
    
    using Juniper
    using Ipopt
    using JuMP
    using LinearAlgebra 
    using Base.Threads
    using Cbc
    using DifferentialEquations
    using Trapz
    function mat_exp(x::AbstractVector{T},dim,num_terms,A) where T
    
        sum = zeros(Complex{T},(dim,dim))
        A[1,1] = A[1,1]*x[1]
        A[2,2] = A[2,2]*x[2]
    
       return exp(A)-1
    end
    
    function exp_approx_no_big(x::AbstractVector{T},dim,num_terms,A) where T
    
        sum = zeros(Complex{T},(dim,dim))
        A[1,1] = A[1,1]*x[1]
        A[2,2] = A[2,2]*x[2]
    
        for k=0:num_terms-1
        
        sum  = sum + (1.0/factorial(k))*A^k
        end
    
        return norm(sum)-1
    end
    function exp_approx_big(x::AbstractVector{T},dim,num_terms,A) where  T
    
        sum = zeros(Complex{T},(dim,dim))
        A[1,1] = A[1,1]*x[1]
        A[2,2] = A[2,2]*x[2]
    
        for k=0:num_terms-1
        
        sum  = sum + (1.0/factorial(big(k)))*A^k
        end
    
        return norm(sum)-1
    
    
    end
    
    
    
    
    optimizer = Juniper.Optimizer
    nl_solver= optimizer_with_attributes(Ipopt.Optimizer, "print_level" => 0)
    mip_solver = optimizer_with_attributes(Cbc.Optimizer, "logLevel" => 0, "threads"=>nthreads())
    m = Model(optimizer_with_attributes(optimizer, "nl_solver"=>nl_solver, "mip_solver"=>mip_solver))
    
    @variable(m, 0.0<=x[1:2]<=1.0)
    dim=5
    A=zeros(Complex,(dim,dim))
    for k=1:dim
    A[k,k]=1.0
    end
    println(A)
    
    
    
    f(x...) = exp_approx_no_big(collect(x),dim,20,A)
    g(x...) = exp_approx_big(collect(x),dim,40,A)
    h(x...) = mat_exp(collect(x),dim,20,A)
    register(m, :f, 2, f; autodiff = true)
    @NLobjective(m, Min, f(x...))
    
    
    optimize!(m)
    
    
    println(JuMP.value.(x))
    println(JuMP.objective_value(m))
    println(JuMP.termination_status(m))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems with your `mat_exp` function:

- It modifies `A` in-place, so repeated calls will not do what you think
- It returns `exp(x) - 1`, which is a matrix. JuMP only supports scalar calls
- You probably meant `norm(exp(x)) - 1`
- But ForwardDiff doesn't support differentiating through `exp`

```
julia> using ForwardDiff

julia> function mat_exp(x::AbstractVector{T}) where {T}
           A = zeros(Complex{T}, (dim, dim))
           for k = 1:dim
               A[k, k] = one(T)
           end
           A[1, 1] = A[1, 1] * x[1]
           A[2, 2] = A[2, 2] * x[2]
           return norm(exp(A)) - one(T)
       end
mat_exp (generic function with 3 methods)

julia> ForwardDiff.gradient(mat_exp, [0.5, 0.5])
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching exp(::Matrix{Complex{ForwardDiff.Dual{ForwardDiff.Tag{typeof(mat_exp), Float64}, Float64, 2}}})
Closest candidates are:
  exp(::StridedMatrix{var"#s832"} where var"#s832"<:Union{Float32, Float64, ComplexF32, ComplexF64}) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/LinearAlgebra/src/dense.jl:557
  exp(::StridedMatrix{var"#s832"} where var"#s832"<:Union{Integer, Complex{var"#s831"} where var"#s831"<:Integer}) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/LinearAlgebra/src/dense.jl:558
  exp(::Diagonal) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/LinearAlgebra/src/diagonal.jl:603
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] mat_exp(x::Vector{ForwardDiff.Dual{ForwardDiff.Tag{typeof(mat_exp), Float64}, Float64, 2}})
   @ Main ./REPL[34]:8
 [2] vector_mode_dual_eval!(f::typeof(mat_exp), cfg::ForwardDiff.GradientConfig{ForwardDiff.Tag{typeof(mat_exp), Float64}, Float64, 2, Vector{ForwardDiff.Dual{ForwardDiff.Tag{typeof(mat_exp), Float64}, Float64, 2}}}, x::Vector{Float64})
   @ ForwardDiff ~/.julia/packages/ForwardDiff/jJIvy/src/apiutils.jl:37
 [3] vector_mode_gradient(f::typeof(mat_exp), x::Vector{Float64}, cfg::ForwardDiff.GradientConfig{ForwardDiff.Tag{typeof(mat_exp), Float64}, Float64, 2, Vector{ForwardDiff.Dual{ForwardDiff.Tag{typeof(mat_exp), Float64}, Float64, 2}}})
   @ ForwardDiff ~/.julia/packages/ForwardDiff/jJIvy/src/gradient.jl:106
 [4] gradient(f::Function, x::Vector{Float64}, cfg::ForwardDiff.GradientConfig{ForwardDiff.Tag{typeof(mat_exp), Float64}, Float64, 2, Vector{ForwardDiff.Dual{ForwardDiff.Tag{typeof(mat_exp), Float64}, Float64, 2}}}, ::Val{true})
   @ ForwardDiff ~/.julia/packages/ForwardDiff/jJIvy/src/gradient.jl:19
 [5] gradient(f::Function, x::Vector{Float64}, cfg::ForwardDiff.GradientConfig{ForwardDiff.Tag{typeof(mat_exp), Float64}, Float64, 2, Vector{ForwardDiff.Dual{ForwardDiff.Tag{typeof(mat_exp), Float64}, Float64, 2}}}) (repeats 2 times)
   @ ForwardDiff ~/.julia/packages/ForwardDiff/jJIvy/src/gradient.jl:17
 [6] top-level scope
   @ REPL[35]:1
```

I also don't know why you're using Juniper, or that you have a bunch of other packages installed.

If you want to have a discussion on this, come join the community forum: https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/opt/13. (It's much better for back-and-forth than stackoverflow.) Someone might have suggestions, but I don't know of an AD tool in Julia that can differentiate through a matrix exponential.

Comment: Hey Oscar- first thanks for pointing out this (obvious) and big mistake on my side. Thanks for refering me to a more appropiate place to ask this question (I didn't know this other discussion board existed). I'll be sure to post to get feedback from folks like you and others who know the in's and out's of this library.

Comment: We advertise the community forum on https://jump.dev, in "Resources for getting started" it's also under the "Community" tab. It's also in a green "tip" on the first page of the docs: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/. Any suggestions for how we could make this more obvious?

Comment: Hey Oscar, I think for 99% of folks they would find it easily, as you point out - I'm just the 1% that didn't read the documentation, and come from the python scientific computing community where we ussually do things on stack overflow. Thanks for pointing me to this great resource though.